# Firebase Rules syntax error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i have a little error in my syntax , i want to make the "version" child public for everyone to read but the other rules private

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"

  },
    "version": {
      ".read": true

    }


}
```

Error at line 7 ("version" line)

> Expected '}'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your "version" child *inside* "rules".  You have it outside.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",

    "version": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! gonna mark this as correct after the 10 minutes delay

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",

    "version": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```